# Division of one polynomial by another

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

I want to know that if there are two polynomials, with one being divisor and another dividend. If divisor has more than one root, and dividend is divisible by not all, but at least one of them; then would the dividend be still completely divisible by divisor.
I have no mathematical basis, but expect that in order for the divisor to completely divide the dividend; the dividend must be divisible by all the roots of the divisor.

If a suitable mathematical theorem or basis is available, then I would be thankful for that. Also, if there is ramification of this issue in abstract algebra, then it would be of much interest to me.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @KennyLau: But, then what can be a suitable mathematical term for the divisor's all roots not dividing dividend, but at least one root dividing still. Particularly, if this issue has ramifications in abstract algebra.

Comment: "can be simplified", "have common factor", etc.

Comment: @KennyLau: I can easily understand the second term, i.e. the dividend and divisor have a common factor. But the first term: "can be simplified" is not expressible / usable by me to express the partial divisibility of the dividend by the roots of the divisor.